# Golang Server 404 on Static Pages

Tags: go, server, static

I am working on a compiled Golang server that displays a home page, and upload page, and a file repository. It can also upload a file to its backend. The goal is to put this into a container and use it.

Code: https://github.com/thatMacAdmin/go-webserver

If I do the following on my local machine:
`go run webserver.go`

Then it works as expected. The page in `/static/index.html` loads. I can upload files etc (as long as the repo exists in the right location). However when I build this and put it in a docker container, the repo file list works, and the upload endpoint exists, however the two static html pages get 404 errors.

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't http://localhost:8080 work to display my home page in the container but it does work with the go run method?

Thanks,
Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was that Docker uses `/` as its relative path unless you tell it otherwise. In this instance my code expected the relative path to be where my server binary was located. In my case:

```
/server
```

Setting the WORKDIR option correctly in my Dockerfile fixed this.

Example:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN mkdir -p /server/static
COPY webserver /server
COPY static /server/static
WORKDIR /server
ENTRYPOINT ["/server/webserver"] 
EXPOSE 8080
```

Answer (score -1):

The static files are not automatically included in your binary. So you need to make sure that the running application working directory (even if it is running within a docker container) contains the folder "static" and its files. Otherwise the file is not found and you get an 404.

One alternative to this is to compile the static files into your binary. You can use [gofiles](https://gitlab.com/martinr92/gofiles) for this.

Comment: The entire static folder and compiled web server binary are placed into a docker container in the same configuration as they are in the GitHub repository.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by using a static path of /server/static. Any thoughts on why the relative path does not work?

Comment: With the relative path, go is searching within the working directory (can be different to the directory where the binary is located). Can you share more details about your docker container?